# Why does ifconfig only show the first IP of a network interface configured with systemd-networkd?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ip, systemd, ifconfig

So I'm not sure what's going on here, but I've duplicated this problem on multiple different servers on Ubuntu 17.04 (up to date) yet I can't find any other reports of this, so I have to imagine I'm doing something wrong. I just have no idea what.

In short, I can configure an interface just fine with `systemd.networkd` to have multiple IPs. They'll show up like so:

```bsh
root@nuprobe:/etc/systemd/network# ip addr show dev mike-home
11: mike-home: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 4088 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d8:eb:97:XX:XX:XX brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.12.1.2/24 brd 10.12.1.255 scope global mike-home
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.12.1.3/24 brd 10.12.1.255 scope global secondary mike-home
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Yet if I query the same thing using `ifconfig`, whereas the subsequent IPs would normally get pesudo-network devices named `mike-home:N` (N being a number), this is the entirety of the output:

```bsh
root@nuprobe:/etc/systemd/network# ifconfig
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 4559  bytes 659801 (659.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4559  bytes 659801 (659.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

mike-home: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 4088
        inet 10.12.1.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.12.1.255
        ether d8:eb:97:b6:0b:64  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 54202  bytes 67720330 (67.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 36690  bytes 4503051 (4.5 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Any ideas as to what's going on?

Here is my `systemd.network` file:

```
[Match]
Name=mike-home

[Link]
MACAddress=d8:eb:97:b6:0b:64
MTUBytes=4088
ARP=true

[Network]
BindCarrier=mike-home
Description=Mike Home Network
DHCP=no
IPv4LLRoute=no
MulticastDNS=no
LinkLocalAddressing=no
Domains=vasto.la

[Address]
Address=10.12.1.2/24
Broadcast=10.12.1.255
PreferredLifetime=forever

[Address]
Address=10.12.1.3/24
Broadcast=10.12.1.255
PreferredLifetime=forever

[Route]
Gateway=10.12.1.1
Source=10.12.1.0/24
PreferredSource=10.12.1.2
Destination=10.12.5.0/24
Scope=link

[Route]
Gateway=10.12.1.1
Source=10.12.1.0/24
PreferredSource=10.12.1.2
Destination=10.12.10.0/24
Scope=link

[Route]
Gateway=10.12.1.1
Source=10.12.1.0/24
PreferredSource=10.12.1.2
Destination=10.12.20.0/24
Scope=link

# vim: set filetype=systemd:
```

Any guesses (more than) welcome.

Comment: As a side note: 1) Broadcast can always be calculated from the netmask, so don't bother setting it unless you have a _really_ special network. 2) Source-based routing (`Source=`) is only implemented on Linux for IPv6. If you actually needed it for IPv4, you'd have to use `ip rule`. 3) Routes with a gateway by definition aren't link-scoped...

Comment: Good catch(es). Fixed all of those (removed `Source=`, `Scope=` and `Broadcast=`) but may have to add back `Source=` but now I'm getting the error `Could not set route. Network is unreachable.` three times when the interface comes up. Any idea what that would be due to? I can ping `10.12.1.1` and ethtool reports a good link but the routes aren't being added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Current Linux tools no longer create "alias" pseudo-interfaces as they have no need to do so – starting with Linux kernel **2.4.x**, the modern Netlink-based network configuration API allows them to directly assign a list of addresses to the same eth0 interface using add/remove operations.

Meanwhile ifconfig uses a much older "SIOCGIFADDR" API to retrieve the IP addresses, which doesn't support managing more than one address per interface (e.g. it only has a "set" operation that overwrites the current address, but no "add" or "remove"). Alias interfaces only existed as a workaround for this limitation.

These days the alias pseudo-interfaces aren't "real" – they're emulated from the eth0 address list, by setting the 'label' parameter of each address. For example, if you need a specific address to be visible through "eth0:0" (whether for ifconfig, or some other ancient tool), you can ask systemd-networkd to set that as the label:

```
[Address]
Address=10.12.1.3/24
Label=mike-home:0
```

```
ip addr add 10.12.1.3/24 dev mike-home label mike-home:0
```

However, this shouldn't really be necessary in practice – all your additional addresses will work correctly without "labels" assigned; it's *only* the 'ifconfig' tool that cannot see them.

(There is no fundamental reason why Linux's ifconfig couldn't use Netlink for all its operations – as far as I know it's just that nobody has stepped up to port it to Netlink, so the tool remains stuck in the past. Don't use it, use `ip`.)

---

All of this is specific to Linux. On various BSD systems, for example, ifconfig is still the primary network configuration tool and is kept up-to-date together with the rest of the system.

Comment: thanks a ton for the explanation! The `Label` isn't working for me though. Are you sure it should? Best I can tell, its because systemd isn't accepting the colon in it. In any cause I guess I should move over to `ip` then. Just weird this wasn't mentioned anywhere and the labeling isn't done by default.

Comment: It works with `ip addr add`. It's possible that networkd automatically adds the `eth0:` prefix, so try just `Label=0` instead. (I'm guessing it's not done by default because the ioctl API is IPv4-only and limited in many other ways; it would be wasted effort.)